# Displaying images from JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Trying to display the cover art with the results. Something in the img src tag is causing the app not to load. If I just point the img to data.tracks[i].album.name (obviously not a real url, but enough to test if it's working) it pastes it in just fine, but the moment I change it to paste the url in place, it makes the whole app stop working.

```
$('#findTracks').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // override/don't submit form
                $('#recommendations').empty();
                var artist = $('#artist').val();
                var userid = "";
                var playlistid = "";

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=' + artist,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.tracks.length > 0) {
                            var tracksLength = data.tracks.length, html = '';
                            for (var i=0; i<tracksLength; i++) {
                                var href = '';
                                if (data.tracks[i].album.availability.territories.indexOf(' GB ') !== -1) { // data.tracks[i].href
                                    href = data.tracks[i].href;
                                    href = 'makeReq(\''+data.tracks[i].name + ' by '+data.tracks[i].artists[0].name+'\')';
                                    html += '<li><a href="#" onclick="' + href + '">' +data.tracks[i].name + ' by '+data.tracks[i].artists[0].name+ ' <img src="' +data.tracks[i].album.images[0].url+ '" /></a>';html += '</li>';

                                    html += '</li>';
                                }
                            }
                            $('#third').css('display', 'block');
                            $('#recommendations').append(html);
                        } else {
                            $('#recommendations').append('<li>No matches returned.</li>');
                            $('#third').css('display', 'none');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert("The Spotify API failed to return a response.");
                    }
                });                   
            });
```

This is my first time ever coding in javascript so please go easy on me! lol

EDIT:

This seems to be running well! However, many of the songs do nothing when I click on them

For example, type "Don't Stop" and only "The Black Eyed Peas - Don’t Stop The Party" works out of the first ten...anybody know why?

also, anybody known why "if (data.tracks[i].album.availability.territories.indexOf(' GB ') !== -1)" is in there? If I take it out this all stops working...I am not in G.B.

Comment: are you looking at the html? what does the img src say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the console you are getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

looking at the data the query returns we notice that data.tracks[i].album returns

```
{
    "released": "2006",
    "href": "spotify:album:2knAf4wg8Gff8q1bXiXCTz",
    "name": "The Dutchess",
    "availability": {
        "territories": "MX"
    }
}
```

there is no property `images` so when you call

```
data.tracks[i].album.images[0]
```

you get the undefined error, causing the script to halt execution.
I'm unfamiliar with the spootify api but taking a quick glance at the api theres the endpoint for [get-album](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-album/). Heres what I was able to come up with to get the album art

```js
$.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=Fergie",function(data){
   var albumId = data.tracks[97].album.href.split(":")[2];
   $.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/" + albumId,function(albumResponse){
       var firstImage = albumResponse.images[0];
       $('body').append($('<img/>',{
          src : firstImage.url,
          width : firstImage.width,
          height : firstImage.height
       }));
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

You should research more into how to get the album art since I'm unsure if this is the optimal solution.

The [search](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-search-item/#complete) endpoint you mentioned is different from the one your using.

```
   One your using
   url: 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=' + artist,
   One you linked to
   url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + artist + '&type=track,artist&market=GB',
```

Heres your solution with the change in endpoint

```js
$('#findTracks').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // override/don't submit form
  $('#recommendations').empty();
  var artist = $('#artist').val();
  var userid = "";
  var playlistid = "";

  $.ajax({
    //url: 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=' + artist,
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + artist + '&type=track,artist&market=GB',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.tracks.items.length > 0) {
        data.tracks = data.tracks.items
        data.artists = data.artists.items
        var tracksLength = data.tracks.length,
          html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < tracksLength; i++) {
          var href = '';
          href = data.tracks[i].href;
          href = 'makeReq(\'' + data.tracks[i].name + ' by ' + data.tracks[i].artists[0].name + '\')';
          html += '<li><a href="#" onclick="' + href + '">' + data.tracks[i].name + ' by ' + data.tracks[i].artists[0].name + ' <img src="' + data.tracks[i].album.images[0].url + '" /></a>';
          html += '</li>';
          html += '</li>';

        }
        $('#third').css('display', 'block');
        $('#recommendations').append(html);
      } else {
        $('#recommendations').append('<li>No matches returned.</li>');
        $('#third').css('display', 'none');
      }
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert("The Spotify API failed to return a response.");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Artist:
<input type="text" id="artist" />
<button id="findTracks">Find Tracks</button>
<div id="recommendations"></div>
```

Comment: That's weird, it should be getting the images

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-search-item/#complete

Comment: @TimothyRichardElliot I've added an edit about the api you linked to

Comment: My next problem is how to get it to send to my email...I was originally created a script to send the song requested directly to a "Requests" playlist on my spotify account, but then I realized that this required oauth...now I'm trying to pass it through php to my email